# function factory in R to generate functions that compute k-percentiles with multiple k

Tags: r

I want to write a simple function factory that can enerate functions that compute k-percentiles with multiple k.

my code :

```
genKpercentile = function(...) {
l = list(...)
funList = list()
l[[..k]]
return(function(x) quantile(x, probs = k*0.01))
}
genKpercentile(25,50,75)(any_dataset) #find the 25,50,75 percentile in any dataset
```

but I am new to R so I can not sure that how to achieve my purpose.
can anyone master can help me to correct my code to be able to generate multiple k percentile.

thank you very much.

I can use one k to generate k percentile :

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars

genKpercentile = function(k) {
  return(function(x) quantile(x, probs = k*0.01))
}

genKpercentile(25)(mtcars$mpg)
```

but if I want to generate multiple k, I do not know how to write my R code...

Comment: What do you mean by percentiles of a dataset? Percentiles with respect to what variable?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and the expected output you would get? This will make it easier to understand what you are wanting.

Comment: for example, a R built-in data set "mtcars" with variable "mpg", I want to use a function factory to find the multiple k percentile in mtcars$mpg. such like 25th, 50th, 75th...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
any_dataset = rnorm(1000)
genKpercentile = function(...) {
  l = unlist(list(...))
  return(function(x) quantile(x, probs = l*0.01))
}

genKpercentile(25,50,75)(any_dataset) #find the 25,50,75 percentile in any dataset
```

Or, even more simply

```
genKpercentile = function(...) function(x) quantile(x, probs = c(...)*0.01)
```

The point being, that you need to turn `...` into a vector rather than a list

Comment: thank you very much. it seems to solve my problem. it works.